# Translating "revisited" in a title

Tags: translation, english-to-german, single-word-request

How would you translate e.g. "Geometry Revisited" in the context of a [book title](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0883856190)?  Or more generally, "X Revisited" where X is any topic, for example "Penguins Revisited".

Google Translate suggests "Geometrie nochmals besucht" which doesn't sound quite as catchy as the English version...

Answer (score 5):

If you are not satisfied with the google translation, nowadays people use a mashup of languages. German and English are no different, it's called `Denglisch` meaning you can probably call it `Geometrie Revisited`.

If not, then my recommendation is: either `Geometrie neu-betrachtet.` or `Geometrie neu-beleuchtet.`

Run those through google translate and see if it resonates the same as your original English title.

Comment: The suggestions are not bad but I would omit the dash ("neu betrachtet"/"neu beleuchtet")

Comment: I like your second paragraph, but not the first.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the the way the material is revisited, but these are other possibilities:

Geometrie

- neu überdacht
- aus neuer Sicht
- neu aufgegriffen
- erneut augegriffen
- wieder aufgegriffen

Answer (score 2):

Es mag heute seltsam klingen, aber über Jahrzehnte war es in der Welt der deutschsprachig publizierenden Wissenschaft, namentlich in Geistesfächern wie Geschichte und Linguistik, sehr verbreitet, Zeitschriftenaufsätze zu speziellen Themen, die schon öfters diskutiert worden waren, und zu denen der Forscher einen weiteren Gedanken fügen wollte, mit

> Nochmals zu...

zu betiteln, also etwa:

> Nochmals zum Tod im Mörser: Starben so osmanische Schejchülislame?
>
> Nochmals zum brabantischen Adverb brāͅ
>
> Nochmals zum Hildebrandliede

Ach was, Jahrzehnte. Man findet solche Überschriften schon im 19. Jahrhundert. Das letzte Beispiel ist von 1891.

Answer (score 0):

Evelyn Waughs [Brideshead revisited](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brideshead_Revisited)  is in German titled *Wiedersehen mit Brideshead*; *Wiedersehen* is primarily used for persons and locations, but you only want to see persons again, which you find interesting and like to spend some further time with.

A shorter alternative would sinply be *zum zweiten (Mal)* as used by an auctioneer counting-down the chances for bids.

Answer (score 0):

Simply

> Geometrie neu gedacht

came to my mind while reading my predecessors.

Alternative:

> Geometrie in neuem Licht